# How to get rotation in FLARToolKit?

Tags: flash, flartoolkit

How do you get the rotation of the marker in FLARToolKit?
All that I can find is how to do it with papervision3D but since I am using Unity3 for the 3D, this is not optimal.

Thanks in advance

/Jens

Answer (score 0):

Hey,
I believe the latest version of flar toolkit has support for away3D,papervision3D, sandy3D and alternativa3d.